# ¿Cambiar botón al activar card hoover y hacerlo diagonal?

Tags: html, css

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer que el botón cambie cuando se activa el hoover y como puedo agregarle un efecto de entrada al hover.  Esto lo hago con css o javascript?

me pueden explicar como puedo hacer para que el botón me quede en diagonal?
y que este cambie al activar el hoover?

La idea es hacer algo muy parecido a esto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcReojq0mV3U20shKN-G8o7_k1O2LyuXvkS71FERrbDwhgtRl8ij&usqp=CAU);
}

#hover-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.card__button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 3;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  color:#fff;
}

.card__hover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image:url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSsQcGcKElwdlBt7YUGsT_djyGNDbHoRIWEfSwddiuY-m4XXAKL&usqp=CAU);
}
.card__hover p {
  color:red;
  font-size:22px;
}

#hover-toggle:checked + .card__hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, incidunt. Ducimus fuga obcaecati, quo eveniet ut temporibus iste veniam eaque?</p>
  </div>
  <label for="hover-toggle" class="card__button">
    x
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hover-toggle">
  <div class="card__hover" id="card-hover">
    <p>Card Hover</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué cambio debe tener en el hover?

Comment: Hola @BetaM en el botón cambia de un signo (+)  a una (x).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo del siguiente modo:

- Tienes un div que a su vez sirve de contenedor de un enlace `a` que hará las veces de botón
- Le aplicamos al div un display con el valor de flex para poder manipular la orientación y acomodo de sus elementos internos, en este caso el botón
- De la propiedad border usamos: width, style y color para poder crear la figura del triángulo
- El contenido del signo de + y el signo de x cuando se hace hover lo conseguimos con:

  - la pseudoelemento before y la clave content para signar el contenido
  - Usamos de nuevo el mismo pseudoelemento pero esta vez para poder acceder con la pseudoclase hover cuando el usuario pase el cursor y de nuevo con content modificamos el contenido
- Como el contenido generado por el pseudoelemento se descuadró entonces lo pongo con position absolute y lo muevo con bottom y left para que quede dentro de su contenedor

**EJEMPLO**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <style>
        body {
          font-size: 1.5em;
        }
        div {
          width: 300px;
          height: 200px;
          background-color: tomato;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: flex-end;
          align-items: flex-end;
          border: 1px solid;
        }
        a {
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
          border-style: solid;
          border-width: 0 0 80px 80px;
          border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;

        }
        a::before {
          content: "+";
          position: absolute;
          left: 280px;
          bottom: 195px;
        }
        a:hover::before {
          content: "x";
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
      <a href=""></a>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Visualmente esto sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Enlaces de interés**

- [Generador de figuras con CSS online](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)

Comment: Amigo como puedo hacer para mantener el (x) activo es que solo cambia pero hover y no cambia el content.

Comment: Explicame mejor aparte de la X lo que quieres que cambie por que no es claro

Comment: label.card__button::before {
    content: "+";
    position: absolute;
    left: -16px;
    bottom: -41px;
    font-size: 22px;
}

label.card__button:hover::before {
          content: "x";
}

Comment: como vez en la imagen de ejemplo cuando el card hover esta activo la idea es que el botón quede con una X para que el usuario sepa que puede cerrarlo.